# Question regarding a charger modification for a Dell 3100 docking station

Tags: charger, wire, amperage, port, voltmeter

I'm quite new and inexperienced to this so I would appreciate any guidance I can get.

Given the quarantine situation I need to work from home more so I purchased a used D3100 docking station but with no charger. I have an adjustable charger that I cut and modified with a pin that would fit the charging port (it was quite challenging to find for this model)

**This was the modification I made**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6V2y.jpg

**These are the charger specs**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqG3o.jpg

**These are the D3100 specs**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pbja.jpg

I will use isolation tape later, I know it looks pretty ghetto right now.

My problem: I can get 19V across the wire (by measurement with a voltmeter) but only 1 amps.

**The voltmeter I used and settings for measuring amperage**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WUP7.jpg

The charger shows it can deliver up to 4A when at 20V which should be plenty given the specs of this docking station however I keep getting 1A. Why is that? Am I getting something wrong or is the charger busted.

The docking station does not power up at all right now. I tried it with an original charger from work and it worked just fine there.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have the polarity correct?

Comment: You can’t measure the output current by connecting the ammeter directly to the power supply output connector.

Comment: I connected the ammmeter to each exposed cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These Dell products for the (Latitude series laptops) use power adapters that may look like they use **two** connections but these connectors are actually using **three** connections.

The third connection is a **data** connection that allows the laptop (and possibly the docking station as well) to **recognize** the power adapter and to know its power rating.

If you try to charge a Dell Latitude laptop with a non-Dell power adapter the laptop will complain at startup that it doesn't recognize the adapter and that it will not charge its battery due to this.

TLDR: use a Dell adapter with this Dell docking station. As you have found, using a different adapter will give weird and unexpected results.

Note that even the Dell Latitude power adapters from the much older D-series laptops (Like Latitude D620, D830 etc) use the same plug and identification system so usually these older adapters work fine on the newer systems. These power adapters (for Dell Latitude) are very common and easy to find/buy in used condition.

Comment: Thank you for this information! I will look for one of those adapters.